# How to compare 2 columns of a table through dynamic querying

Tags: python, mysql, django, django-queryset

Have a requirement in dynamic querying where i would like to compare 2 columns of a table say "column_a" and "column_b" (all columns are strings). The actual columns to compare are decided at run-time.

I'm using kwargs to create a dictionary. But Django assumes that RHS is an absolute value & not a column of the same table. Using F() is an option, but i cant find any documentation of using F() in kwargs.

if i use kwargs = {'predicted_value':'actual_value'}
'actual_value' is used as a literal string instead of column name

How do i use something like:
kwargs = {'predicted_value':F('actual_value')} and pass it as Model.objects.filter(**kwargs)

Alternately, is there a way to use F('column') in LHS ?
e.g. Model.objects.filter(F(column1_name) = F(column2_name))

Comment: What's RHS/LHS? kwargs is a dictionary. You seem rather confused. Just pass `objects.filter` a dictionary built dynamically, if I understand the problem well

Comment: Oh no no, you can use de `F` function in the query. `Model.objects.filter(some_col=F(kwargs.get('predicted_value')))`. I  haven't did this before, but you can give it a try

Comment: @Pynchia - LHS=Left Hand Side. RHS=Right Hand Side. Think of key/value pair in dictionary. How do i specify a column name instead of a constant in the value side.

Comment: @Gocht - Thanks! But how do i dynamically select "some_col" in your example ?

Comment: I have just tested kwargs = {'predicted_value':F('actual_value')} and it worked, Have you tried it?

Comment: @Gocht - yes, it worked! Now not sure, why it hadn't worked earlier. But if you provide your comment as an answer, i'll  mark it as correct answer. Thanks a ton!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a non-dynamic filter field, I would use:

```
from django.db.models import F

Model.objects.filter(some_col=F(kwargs.get('predicted_value')))
```

But if you need it all dynamically, you can try with:

```
kwargs = {'predicted_value':F('actual_value')}
Model.objects.filter(**kwargs)
```

You can even access related fields:

```
kwargs = {'fk_field__somefield':F('actual_value')}
Model.objects.filter(**kwargs)
```